$L_2$-norm consistency of kernel density estimation
The consistency results for kernel density estimation which I can find are almost all for the $L_1$-norm or $L_\infty$-norm, like in this paper or this paper. I can't simply generalize them to $L_2$-norm since on a infinite measure field like $\mathbb{R}$, the relation of $L_2$ and $L_1$ norm is unclear. So could anyone point me a consistency result for the $L_2$-norm?

I don't know if this suits your needs, but there is the following $L^2$ estimate for kernel density estimators in Alexandre B. Tsybakov's Introduction to Nonparametric Estimation (reformulated so that this answer is self-contained, all mistakes are mine) :

Theorem 1.2 : Assume that the probability density $p$ to be estimated lies in the Nikol'ski space $\mathcal{H}(\beta,L) $ for some $\beta,L>0$. Assume that the kernel $K$ used to construct the Kernel density estimator is a kernel of order $\ell=\lfloor\beta\rfloor$, square integrable, and satisfying
$$\int_{\mathbb R}|u|^\beta |K(u)|\ du<\infty. $$
Then for any $n\ge 1$, the kernel estimator $\hat p_n$ with kernel $K$ and bandwidth $h:= \alpha n^{-\frac{1}{2\beta+1}}$ for any fixed constant $\alpha>0$ satisfies
$$\mathbb E_p \left[\int(\hat p_n(x) - p(x))^2\ dx\right] \le Cn^{-\frac{2\beta}{2\beta+1}},$$
where $C>0$ is a constant which depends only on $\alpha, \beta, L$ and the kernel $K$. In particular, the above estimate holds true uniformly over all $p\in \mathcal{H}(\beta,L)$.

The book contains other related results which you might find interesting.

In case you don't have access to the book, here is the definition of a "kernel of order $\ell$" (from the same book) :

Definition 1.3: Let $\ell\ge 1$ be an integer, we say that $K :\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a kernel of order $\ell$ if the functions $u\mapsto u^j K(u) $ for $j=0,1,\ldots,\ell$ are integrable and satisfy
$$\int K(u) du =1,\quad \int u^j K(u) du = 0,\ j= 1,\ldots,\ell. $$

